# Can't get unique word/phrase counter to work - Python

Tags: python, shell, keyword

I'm having trouble getting anything to write in my outut file (word_count.txt).

I expect the script to review all 500 phrases in my phrases.txt document, and output a list of all the words and how many times they appear.

```
    from re import findall,sub
    from os import listdir
    from collections import Counter

    # path to folder containg all the files
    str_dir_folder = '../data'

    # name and location of output file
    str_output_file = '../data/word_count.txt'

    # the list where all the words will be placed
    list_file_data = '../data/phrases.txt'

    # loop through all the files in the directory
    for str_each_file in listdir(str_dir_folder):
        if str_each_file.endswith('data'):

    # open file and read
    with open(str_dir_folder+str_each_file,'r') as file_r_data:
        str_file_data = file_r_data.read()

    # add data to list
    list_file_data.append(str_file_data)

    # clean all the data so that we don't have all the nasty bits in it
    str_full_data = ' '.join(list_file_data)
    str_clean1 = sub('t','',str_full_data)
    str_clean_data = sub('n',' ',str_clean1)

    # find all the words and put them into a list
    list_all_words = findall('w+',str_clean_data)

    # dictionary with all the times a word has been used
    dict_word_count = Counter(list_all_words)

    # put data in a list, ready for output file
    list_output_data = []
    for str_each_item in dict_word_count:
        str_word = str_each_item
        int_freq = dict_word_count[str_each_item]

        str_out_line = '&quot;%s&quot;,%d' % (str_word,int_freq)

        # populates output list
        list_output_data.append(str_out_line)

    # create output file, write data, close it
    file_w_output = open(str_output_file,'w')
    file_w_output.write('n'.join(list_output_data))
    file_w_output.close()
```

Any help would be great (especially if I'm able to actually output 'single' words within the output list.

thanks very much.

Comment: You have indention problem in the code you pasted. Indent lines from `with` statement to put them inside the loop.

Comment: Hey Simon, it looks like you might be new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: Thanks @robertrodkey all done. Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would be helpful if we got more information such as what you've tried and what sorts of error messages you received.  As kaveh commented above, this code has some major indentation issues.  Once I got around those, there were a number of other logic errors to work through.  I've made some assumptions:

- list_file_data is assigned to '../data/phrases.txt' but there is then a
  loop through all file in a directory.  Since you don't have any handling for
  multiple files elsewhere, I've removed that logic and referenced the
  file listed in list_file_data (and added a small bit of error
  handling).  If you do want to walk through a directory, I'd suggest
  using os.walk() (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm)
- You named your file 'pharses.txt' but then check for if the files
  that endswith 'data'.  I've removed this logic.
- You've placed the data set into a list when findall works just fine with strings and ignores special characters that you've manually removed.  Test here:
  https://regex101.com/ to make sure.
- Changed 'w+' to '\w+' - check out the above link
- Converting to a list outside of the output loop isn't necessary - your dict_word_count is a Counter object which has an 'iteritems' method to roll through each key and value.  Also changed the variable name to 'counter_word_count' to be slightly more accurate.
- Instead of manually generating csv's, I've imported csv and utilized the writerow method (and quoting options)

Code below, hope this helps:

```
import csv
import os

from collections import Counter
from re import findall,sub


# name and location of output file
str_output_file = '../data/word_count.txt'
# the list where all the words will be placed
list_file_data = '../data/phrases.txt'

if not os.path.exists(list_file_data):
    raise OSError('File {} does not exist.'.format(list_file_data))

with open(list_file_data, 'r') as file_r_data:
    str_file_data = file_r_data.read()
    # find all the words and put them into a list
    list_all_words = findall('\w+',str_file_data)
    # dictionary with all the times a word has been used
    counter_word_count = Counter(list_all_words)

    with open(str_output_file, 'w') as output_file:
        fieldnames = ['word', 'freq']
        writer = csv.writer(output_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writerow(fieldnames)

        for key, value in counter_word_count.iteritems():
            output_row = [key, value]
            writer.writerow(output_row)
```

Comment: Thank you Robert, hugely helpful. The script now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
from collections import Counter
from glob import glob

def extract_words_from_line(s):
    # make this as complicated as you want for extracting words from a line
    return s.strip().split()

tally = sum(
    (Counter(extract_words_from_line(line)) 
        for infile in glob('../data/*.data')
            for line in open(infile)), 
     Counter())

for k in sorted(tally, key=tally.get, reverse=True):
    print k, tally[k]
```